# Java BufferedWriter Save As operation

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to emulate the Save As functionality in Java.
I want to choose a filename for it as the code I did before only saved it to

```
myData.dat
```

this is used in a menu in my Main.Class which will look up to

```
else if (option.compareTo("8") == 0){
    manualLib.save();}
```

```
  public void save(){
    String content = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < library.size(); i++){
        for (int bar = 0; bar < library.get(i).size(); bar++){
            content += library.get(i).get(bar).getSerial() + "\n";
            content += library.get(i).get(bar).getTitle() + "\n";
            content += library.get(i).get(bar).getAuthor() + "\n";
            content += library.get(i).get(bar).onLoan() + "\n";
            content += library.get(i).get(bar).getBorrower() + "\n";
        }
    }

    Writer output;
    try {
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myData.dat"));
        try {
              output.write(content);
            }
        finally {
              output.close();
              System.out.println("Successfully saved to myData.dat file.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What is a good way of achieving this?

Comment: What's the issue you have?

Comment: i dont want it to automatically save to myData.dat file, but want the user to create a file and name it to save

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html). This will give you an "easy" UI to let the user choose a file (or a filename). Then you will substitute your `myData.dat` with the value returned by `chooser.getSelectedFile().getName()`.

I have not compiled this but your code should in the end look something like:

```
public void save(){
    String content = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < library.size(); i++){
        for (int bar = 0; bar < library.get(i).size(); bar++){
            content += library.get(i).get(bar).getSerial() + "\n";
            content += library.get(i).get(bar).getTitle() + "\n";
            content += library.get(i).get(bar).getAuthor() + "\n";
            content += library.get(i).get(bar).onLoan() + "\n";
            content += library.get(i).get(bar).getBorrower() + "\n";
        }
    }

    Writer output;

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    DatFilter filter = new DatFilter();
    filter.addExtension("dat");
    filter.setDescription(".dat files");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    String fileName = new String();
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    fileName=chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
    }

    try {
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        try {
              output.write(content);
            }
        finally {
              output.close();
              System.out.println("Successfully saved to "+fileName+" file.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then make also class

```
public class DatFilter extends FileFilter {

    //should accept only dirs and .dat files
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
        }

    String extension = null;
        String s = f.getName();
        int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

        if (i > 0 &&  i < s.length() - 1) {
            extension = s.substring(i+1).toLowerCase();
        }

        if (extension != null) {
            if (extension.equals("dat"){
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    //The description of this filter
    public String getDescription() {
        return ".dat Files";
    }
}
```

Comment: i added a public class of ExampleFileFilter and parent shows an error

Comment: added      Frame parent = new Frame();
now parent shows no error
i can name a file and when i submit tells me its created when it isnt

Comment: DDDutch, obviously ExampleFileFilter was not a valid statement. You should provide to JFileChooser a valid FileFilter, either implementing ExampleFileFiler or (like I just made editing my original answer) another one. Please note that I'm writing your code without compiling it so you should take some minutes to review it. Moreover: the parent component is not important, you can use `null`.

Answer (score 0):

- Use a JFileChooser or whatever UI of your choice to get a full path to the target file to create.
- add a parameter to your `save` method to get this path, and use it instead of `myData.dat`
- store the file path in a field of Main.class
- add a `save` without parameter, that calls the `save` parameter using the path stored in Main.class.